# Is there an abstract language that "compiles" to natural languages?

Tags: nlp

Is there an abstract language that "compiles" to natural languages?

For example

```
(verb-love :subject person-1sg :object person-2sg)
```

would compile to "I love you" in English but to "Je t'aime" in French.
With the possibility to add mood, tense, etc.

```
(verb-love :subject person-1sg :object person-2g :tense future)
```

I used S-expressions the example but the syntax doesn't matter.
It does not have to be Turing-complete since a scripting language could generate such code.

Comment: Your expectation of what features natural languages support is quite specific. Many languages require non-optional information which your example does not provide, but also, the set of features which are genuinely universal across languages is quite small.

Comment: This was a toy example, I know that for example the French sentence could be "je t'aime" or "je vous aime" but a compiler could display all the possibilities, ask questions to get the missing information, or have default parameters

Comment: From the linguistic point of view, the existence of such an abstract language would prove the [universal grammar hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_grammar), which is still debated. It wouldn't be easy at all to actually develop such a language, many linguists have tried some version of it. For practical applications there is [NL generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation) which often relies on the same idea, but with a very restricted predefined subset of language.

Comment: look up [GF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_Framework) and [ACG](https://members.loria.fr/PdeGroote/papers/acl01.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is a general question without a clear application. Some may say that depends on the application. Compiling abstract representations into text may not be natural language but it is close enough for some applications.

One of the solutions is Grammatical Framework (GF) https://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html. You can write abstractions and various linearisations in different languages. A good starting point is GF's Resource Grammar Library (RGL) which has a small set of vocabulary and standard sentence structure for a very wide range of languages in the world.
There is a tiny version here on the web demo:
http://cloud.grammaticalframework.org/minibar/minibar.html